# Viewing SVN log history incrementally?

Tags: svn, version-control

Is there any tool which shows the SVN Log history of a file in steps and incremenatlly, like I click a button and it shows next version with the new lines added so that I can browse the history of an entire file from start to end through mere button clicks?. I know there are softwares like Tortoise etc which can do a merge diff, but I wanted a more graphical, and interactive GUI based tool which requires less effort.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Web browser like [Sventon](http://svn.sventon.org/repos/gc/diff/trunk/sventon-webapp/base/pom.xml?revision=HEAD&entries=%2ftrunk%2fsventon-webapp%2fbase%2fpom.xml%402047&entries=%2ftrunk%2fsventon-webapp%2fbase%2fpom.xml%402045&style=sidebyside). This is a link into a Sventon Web browser looking at the Sventon project itself. (Wow! That's Meta!).

This is showing a side-by-side view of Revision 2047 to Revision 2045. There's a button labeled *Diff to previous*. Clicking on that button will diff Revision 2045 to its previous revision, 2044. Clicking on it again will show you the diff between `pom.xml` from Revision 2044 to 2043 of that file.

Does this do what you want? Sventon is easy to setup: You install Java and Tomcat, and add the `sventon.war` file into the `webapps` directory in Tomcat. Startup Tomcat, and Sventon is up and running. You can run Sventon on the same machine as your repo, but that's not a requirement. You could even run it on your local desktop if you so desire.

Comment: I want this on Mac actually, and installing Tomcat on Mac looks very difficult to me

Comment: The difficulty is getting [Java to work on a Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/01/install-java-in-os-x-mountain-lion/). Due to security issues, Java is no longer installed as a default. You have to jump through some hoops to get it up and running. Tomcat is easy. You download it, install it in something like `/opt`, unzip it, and run `/opt/apache-tomcat-x.x/bin/startup.sh` from the command line. To get Sventon to work, you stop Tomcat (shutdown.sh), put the `sventon.war` file in the `webapps` directory, and restart Tomcat. You run it via `http://localhost:8080/svn`. It's really quite simple.